# Why am I getting rendering errors when creating a new android project?

Tags: java, android, intellij-idea

I am simply creating a new android project in intellij, but when I go to view activity_main.xml, the design tab displays empty screens and also gives me an assertion error for rendering.

I am running on JDK 1.8 and Android API 28. I believe the root of the problem is the Android Support plugin. Part of the error message says the there is an "Exception in plugin Android Support". I have tried restarting, reinstalling, invalidating caches, rebuilding project, cleaning project, and changing java/android versions.

Also I tried making a project the same exact way in Android Studio and it worked fine. It is some issue with intellij, presumably from the Android Support plugin.

*UPDATE* - I added the gradle files to the post and noticed an error with many of the android support files that says "Library x has has broken classes path". I marked the files showing errors.

[Here is a screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/v7L3E.png)

Here is the stack trace below.

```
java.lang.AssertionError
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.ClassConverter.rewriteClass(ClassConverter.java:81)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.ClassConverter.rewriteClass(ClassConverter.java:72)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.convertClass(RenderClassLoader.java:184)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClass(RenderClassLoader.java:168)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.loadClassFile(RenderClassLoader.java:149)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassFile(ModuleClassLoader.java:301)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClassFromModuleOrDependency(ModuleClassLoader.java:239)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.load(ModuleClassLoader.java:177)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderClassLoader.findClass(RenderClassLoader.java:61)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:124)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:588)
    at java.base/java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:521)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:224)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadAndParseRClass(ViewLoader.java:536)
    at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadAndParseRClassSilently(ViewLoader.java:509)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallbackImpl.loadAndParseRClass(LayoutlibCallbackImpl.java:849)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderTask.<init>(RenderTask.java:174)
    at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$RenderTaskBuilder.build(RenderService.java:590)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.inflate(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:830)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.renderImpl(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:959)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager.render(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:917)
    at com.android.tools.idea.uibuilder.scene.LayoutlibSceneManager$1.run(LayoutlibSceneManager.java:543)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:324)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:314)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.lambda$flush$1(MergingUpdateQueue.java:264)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:278)
    at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:233)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:231)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.runSafely(Alarm.java:368)
    at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request.run(Alarm.java:355)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:515)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.SchedulingWrapper$MyScheduledFutureTask.run(SchedulingWrapper.java:224)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.doRun(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:207)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor.access$100(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:29)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.lambda$run$0(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:185)
    at com.intellij.util.ConcurrencyUtil.runUnderThreadName(ConcurrencyUtil.java:208)
    at com.intellij.util.concurrency.BoundedTaskExecutor$1.run(BoundedTaskExecutor.java:181)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
```

Gradle Files (Files with errors are marked with ****)

```
Gradle: android.arch.core:common:1.1.1@jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\android.arch.core\common\1.1.1\e55b70d1f5620db124b3e85a7f4bdc7bd48d9f95\common-1.1.1.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\android.arch.core\common\1.1.1\ae9b923fc99c1fc5a7a9b6cedc6df8b2b8529c54\common-1.1.1-sources.jar
Gradle: android.arch.core:runtime:1.1.1@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\runtime-1.1.1.aar\06993535063794a85b2ad2df149b3480\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\runtime-1.1.1.aar\06993535063794a85b2ad2df149b3480\jars\classes.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\android.arch.core\runtime\1.1.1\25df553df10af32bede9dd768a2d15299543d84\runtime-1.1.1-sources.jar
Gradle: android.arch.lifecycle:common:1.1.1@jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\android.arch.lifecycle\common\1.1.1\207a6efae6a3555e326de41f76bdadd9a239cbce\common-1.1.1.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\android.arch.lifecycle\common\1.1.1\bcdaa509a856d1430e736b102f899aa9870a8f83\common-1.1.1-sources.jar
Gradle: android.arch.lifecycle:livedata-core:1.1.1@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\livedata-core-1.1.1.aar\9e28ac33fe15fd92138dcfc30d99c68b\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\livedata-core-1.1.1.aar\9e28ac33fe15fd92138dcfc30d99c68b\jars\classes.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\android.arch.lifecycle\livedata-core\1.1.1\c38818e006ea7a408c05e3090364332d46494ef\livedata-core-1.1.1-sources.jar
Gradle: android.arch.lifecycle:livedata:1.1.1@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\livedata-1.1.1.aar\2b9ca88eeaa286f8ed6cac1460c78cf1\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\livedata-1.1.1.aar\2b9ca88eeaa286f8ed6cac1460c78cf1\jars\classes.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\android.arch.lifecycle\livedata\1.1.1\bf27acaa4953c98cd519756ed7b7caacf94407d4\livedata-1.1.1-sources.jar
Gradle: android.arch.lifecycle:runtime:1.1.1@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\runtime-1.1.1.aar\a469c4958a257a796eaa47ca57a80950\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\runtime-1.1.1.aar\a469c4958a257a796eaa47ca57a80950\jars\classes.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\android.arch.lifecycle\runtime\1.1.1\8e4214221b3797b863dc9998d16abb4af043e784\runtime-1.1.1-sources.jar
Gradle: android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\viewmodel-1.1.1.aar\9bad3326cad811d52d23518885c78d85\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\viewmodel-1.1.1.aar\9bad3326cad811d52d23518885c78d85\jars\classes.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\android.arch.lifecycle\viewmodel\1.1.1\d1cc8e805317f171be63c68341f499acda7e42d6\viewmodel-1.1.1-sources.jar
Gradle: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout-solver:1.1.3@jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.support.constraint\constraint-layout-solver\1.1.3\bde0667d7414c16ed62d3cfe993cff7f9d732373\constraint-layout-solver-1.1.3.jar
Gradle: com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.1.3@aar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\constraint-layout-1.1.3.aar\c7e56119be88bd6f957360cb87bc7695\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\constraint-layout-1.1.3.aar\c7e56119be88bd6f957360cb87bc7695\jars\classes.jar
Gradle: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\espresso-core-3.0.2.aar\280d0fb8a907d8b7dab11c33bd07e03f\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\espresso-core-3.0.2.aar\280d0fb8a907d8b7dab11c33bd07e03f\jars\classes.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.support.test.espresso\espresso-core\3.0.2\433f4f601a3f3835691d80838dd7ff9414931b05\espresso-core-3.0.2-sources.jar
Gradle: com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-idling-resource:3.0.2@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\espresso-idling-resource-3.0.2.aar\86fb3548e88444440102de02037aa7bd\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\espresso-idling-resource-3.0.2.aar\86fb3548e88444440102de02037aa7bd\jars\classes.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.support.test.espresso\espresso-idling-resource\3.0.2\6071e2b310c16836ba475a94df377e2f75928546\espresso-idling-resource-3.0.2-sources.jar
Gradle: com.android.support.test:monitor:1.0.2@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\monitor-1.0.2.aar\965ab1fecfd13092cc376e9a52062315\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\monitor-1.0.2.aar\965ab1fecfd13092cc376e9a52062315\jars\classes.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.support.test\monitor\1.0.2\5764301056100b445e9ba31df7d1b554a55450f6\monitor-1.0.2-sources.jar
Gradle: com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\runner-1.0.2.aar\1697a6ce7c43b221837c8710cbbcbf30\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\runner-1.0.2.aar\1697a6ce7c43b221837c8710cbbcbf30\jars\classes.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.support.test\runner\1.0.2\b2ce2342744a66e935dbc4a298259709a4c1f042\runner-1.0.2-sources.jar
Gradle: com.android.support:animated-vector-drawable:28.0.0@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\animated-vector-drawable-28.0.0.aar\e602df4477cef22b841d3856df1135ad\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\animated-vector-drawable-28.0.0.aar\e602df4477cef22b841d3856df1135ad\jars\classes.jar
Gradle: com.android.support:appcompat-v7:28.0.0@aar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\19b2a02b7636e2dd1cef26e7c352e052\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\19b2a02b7636e2dd1cef26e7c352e052\jars\classes.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\appcompat-v7-28.0.0.aar\19b2a02b7636e2dd1cef26e7c352e052\annotations.zip
Gradle: com.android.support:asynclayoutinflater:28.0.0@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\asynclayoutinflater-28.0.0.aar\a856815b9e3c122b7c6cc0f43c81deba\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\asynclayoutinflater-28.0.0.aar\a856815b9e3c122b7c6cc0f43c81deba\jars\classes.jar
Gradle: com.android.support:collections:28.0.0@jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.support\collections\28.0.0\c1bcdade4d3cc2836130424a3f3e4182c666a745\collections-28.0.0.jar
Gradle: com.android.support:coordinatorlayout:28.0.0@aar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\coordinatorlayout-28.0.0.aar\4b6cf6e3cd0874759e8c4097999a9657\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\coordinatorlayout-28.0.0.aar\4b6cf6e3cd0874759e8c4097999a9657\jars\classes.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\coordinatorlayout-28.0.0.aar\4b6cf6e3cd0874759e8c4097999a9657\annotations.zip
Gradle: com.android.support:cursoradapter:28.0.0@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\cursoradapter-28.0.0.aar\f718356b0b3f25364ab360181a746354\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\cursoradapter-28.0.0.aar\f718356b0b3f25364ab360181a746354\jars\classes.jar
Gradle: com.android.support:customview:28.0.0@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\customview-28.0.0.aar\80e714950b41210bdf97315ed8d8cfd3\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\customview-28.0.0.aar\80e714950b41210bdf97315ed8d8cfd3\jars\classes.jar
Gradle: com.android.support:documentfile:28.0.0@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\documentfile-28.0.0.aar\f294850d491eeba8f7eb8a3794d43846\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\documentfile-28.0.0.aar\f294850d491eeba8f7eb8a3794d43846\jars\classes.jar
Gradle: com.android.support:drawerlayout:28.0.0@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\drawerlayout-28.0.0.aar\4cdb30ffa6fb204d6ea391a7d3722ad8\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\drawerlayout-28.0.0.aar\4cdb30ffa6fb204d6ea391a7d3722ad8\jars\classes.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\drawerlayout-28.0.0.aar\4cdb30ffa6fb204d6ea391a7d3722ad8\annotations.zip
Gradle: com.android.support:interpolator:28.0.0@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\interpolator-28.0.0.aar\aaab0dc38b50ab3f7e3096d51e69485c\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\interpolator-28.0.0.aar\aaab0dc38b50ab3f7e3096d51e69485c\jars\classes.jar
Gradle: com.android.support:loader:28.0.0@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\loader-28.0.0.aar\ac21c4f585d4805adb74a3aa02dbcdfd\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\loader-28.0.0.aar\ac21c4f585d4805adb74a3aa02dbcdfd\jars\classes.jar
Gradle: com.android.support:localbroadcastmanager:28.0.0@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\localbroadcastmanager-28.0.0.aar\4a49537cbe79752e428d861ba12a7ff0\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\localbroadcastmanager-28.0.0.aar\4a49537cbe79752e428d861ba12a7ff0\jars\classes.jar
Gradle: com.android.support:print:28.0.0@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\print-28.0.0.aar\f7054946f55ec5deb3609a904a96880d\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\print-28.0.0.aar\f7054946f55ec5deb3609a904a96880d\jars\classes.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\print-28.0.0.aar\f7054946f55ec5deb3609a904a96880d\annotations.zip
Gradle: com.android.support:slidingpanelayout:28.0.0@aar
    ***C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\slidingpanelayout-28.0.0.aar\c32796eac30d1ed5f1009ca46cc51d05\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\slidingpanelayout-28.0.0.aar\c32796eac30d1ed5f1009ca46cc51d05\jars\classes.jar
Gradle: com.android.support:support-annotations:28.0.0@jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.android.support\support-annotations\28.0.0\ed73f5337a002d1fd24339d5fb08c2c9d9ca60d8\support-annotations-28.0.0.jar
Gradle: com.android.support:support-compat:28.0.0@aar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-28.0.0.aar\c8aa9633aefeb4e4ee317b82409607b3\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-28.0.0.aar\c8aa9633aefeb4e4ee317b82409607b3\jars\classes.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-compat-28.0.0.aar\c8aa9633aefeb4e4ee317b82409607b3\annotations.zip
Gradle: com.android.support:support-core-ui:28.0.0@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-28.0.0.aar\e54c28f15ad19fba6495870ed4a4f61a\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-ui-28.0.0.aar\e54c28f15ad19fba6495870ed4a4f61a\jars\classes.jar
Gradle: com.android.support:support-core-utils:28.0.0@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-utils-28.0.0.aar\8b1fea3c0241c62014f11d8cf87c7bf7\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-core-utils-28.0.0.aar\8b1fea3c0241c62014f11d8cf87c7bf7\jars\classes.jar
Gradle: com.android.support:support-fragment:28.0.0@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-fragment-28.0.0.aar\10b50d96eb352993026b171972dbfa15\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-fragment-28.0.0.aar\10b50d96eb352993026b171972dbfa15\jars\classes.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-fragment-28.0.0.aar\10b50d96eb352993026b171972dbfa15\annotations.zip
Gradle: com.android.support:support-vector-drawable:28.0.0@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-vector-drawable-28.0.0.aar\722a3742719b7d222823e363541c4703\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\support-vector-drawable-28.0.0.aar\722a3742719b7d222823e363541c4703\jars\classes.jar
Gradle: com.android.support:swiperefreshlayout:28.0.0@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\swiperefreshlayout-28.0.0.aar\4c7c2354e330bbea67f132559a57d4de\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\swiperefreshlayout-28.0.0.aar\4c7c2354e330bbea67f132559a57d4de\jars\classes.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\swiperefreshlayout-28.0.0.aar\4c7c2354e330bbea67f132559a57d4de\annotations.zip
Gradle: com.android.support:versionedparcelable:28.0.0@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\versionedparcelable-28.0.0.aar\d140b72dcb00c3bc2c376f8a295dc319\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\versionedparcelable-28.0.0.aar\d140b72dcb00c3bc2c376f8a295dc319\jars\classes.jar
Gradle: com.android.support:viewpager:28.0.0@aar
****C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\viewpager-28.0.0.aar\9208ce7fbe508f4c52ab65557eac86a9\res
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\transforms-1\files-1.1\viewpager-28.0.0.aar\9208ce7fbe508f4c52ab65557eac86a9\jars\classes.jar
Gradle: com.google.code.findbugs:jsr305:2.0.1@jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.google.code.findbugs\jsr305\2.0.1\516c03b21d50a644d538de0f0369c620989cd8f0\jsr305-2.0.1.jar
Gradle: com.squareup:javawriter:2.1.1@jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup\javawriter\2.1.1\67ff45d9ae02e583d0f9b3432a5ebbe05c30c966\javawriter-2.1.1.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\com.squareup\javawriter\2.1.1\5b31387d839a5cdaf5b6de3990da01f7f2b963c5\javawriter-2.1.1-sources.jar
Gradle: javax.inject:javax.inject:1@jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.inject\javax.inject\1\6975da39a7040257bd51d21a231b76c915872d38\javax.inject-1.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\javax.inject\javax.inject\1\a00123f261762a7c5e0ec916a2c7c8298d29c400\javax.inject-1-sources.jar
Gradle: junit:junit:4.12@jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\junit\4.12\2973d150c0dc1fefe998f834810d68f278ea58ec\junit-4.12.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\junit\junit\4.12\a6c32b40bf3d76eca54e3c601e5d1470c86fcdfa\junit-4.12-sources.jar
Gradle: net.sf.kxml:kxml2:2.3.0@jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.sf.kxml\kxml2\2.3.0\ccbc77a5fd907ef863c29f3596c6f54ffa4e9442\kxml2-2.3.0.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\net.sf.kxml\kxml2\2.3.0\309cd2cff7260e465792fda3dcbb063b730d8050\kxml2-2.3.0-sources.jar
Gradle: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-core:1.3@jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\42a25dc3219429f0e5d060061f71acb49bf010a0\hamcrest-core-1.3.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-core\1.3\1dc37250fbc78e23a65a67fbbaf71d2e9cbc3c0b\hamcrest-core-1.3-sources.jar
Gradle: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-integration:1.3@jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-integration\1.3\5de0c73fef18917cd85d0ab70bb23818685e4dfd\hamcrest-integration-1.3.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-integration\1.3\ae7787a563e6a1b1f17fd4ac43be3a3c8830cfda\hamcrest-integration-1.3-sources.jar
Gradle: org.hamcrest:hamcrest-library:1.3@jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-library\1.3\4785a3c21320980282f9f33d0d1264a69040538f\hamcrest-library-1.3.jar
    C:\Users\zfran\.gradle\caches\modules-2\files-2.1\org.hamcrest\hamcrest-library\1.3\47a7ee46628ab7133129cd7cef1e92657bc275e\hamcrest-library-1.3-sources.jar
```

Comment: Please provide both app/project level gradle files.

Comment: I added the files and also an error that I came across in Project Structure -> Libraries. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

JetBrains is aware of this problem.

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-219113

Go back to the previous version of IntelliJ (2019.1.4). For me the previous version is working.